# What is the best way for me to create my abstract class DataType?

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

It has been a *long* time since I have used C-like languages, including C++. My current job has me focused mostly on Python, and the way that C++ handles inheritance is causing me some frustration. I need to be able to read in log files and pull out important bits of information based on pre-defined patterns to look for in said logs.

I have an abstract class `DataType`:

```
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class DataType {
public:
    // Getters
    virtual string GetRawData() const;
    virtual string GetFormattedData() const;

protected:
    // Transform raw data (if possible)
    virtual int Transform(string raw, string &fmt) = 0;

    // A pattern string (regex) to compare against raw_data to see
    // if can be transformed into a normalized format
    static string definition;

    string raw_data;
    string formatted_data;

};
```

As you can see by the pure virtual function `Transform()`, I do not want this class to be able to be instantiated. I will have subclasses for that: `IPv4Address`, `IPv6Address`, `Timestamp`, etc.

I am pretty sure I am slowly getting a handle on the virtual functions and overloading them in derived classes. However, I am still struggling with how best to handle the member variables (`definition`, `raw_data`, and `formatted_data`). Specifically with `definition`, I would really like all derived classes to have their own value, but that variable should be static for each class. My question is *where* do I declare, and *where* do I define?

As it stands now with my derived class `IPv4Address`, when I define `definition` in IPv4Address.h as follows:

```
class IPv4Address : public DataType {
//stuff above
protected:
    // I know the pattern doesn't work matching IP addresses.
    // I'm just trying to get this to compile without error for now.
    static string definition = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
//stuff below
}
```

I get this error:

`in-call initialization of static data member 'std::__cxx11::string IPv4Address::definition of non-literal type`

Do I need to define this variable in the cpp file instead? That doesn't seem right to me, but that doesn't mean much. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't initialize a static variable in the class definition. It needs to be outside the class definition. Also, there is no way to *enforce* each derived class to have a specific static variable (like a pure virtual static variable), unfortunately, so I would leave it out of the base class.

EDIT: Unless you're using C++17 (need to specify) in which you can use `inline` variables. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static. For the record, cppreference is a great resource if you're new to C++. It *will* be frustrating coming from python.

Comment: As an aside, about something that is beyond the scope of the question, I believe [the metaclasses proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0707r3.pdf) would enable something like this.

Comment: How about adding `const`?

Comment: Please clarify how exactly do you intend to use this `definition` variable. It's possible that you are trying to use the wrong language feature to solve your problem.

Comment: @r3musn0x The `definition` variable serves as the "definition" of a DataType derived class. So, for IPv4Address, `definition` would be a regex-style string that raw data input can be compared against to verify whether or not that raw data is or is not an IPv4 address.

Comment: @NathanLee, I meant which method or function will be using this variable and how will it retrieve a different `definition` depending on data type.

Comment: @r3musn0x Oh, sorry I misunderstood. My idea was to do the comparison in `Transform()`. So, within `Transform()`, if the raw data matched the definition, it would be transformed into a normalized format and stored. The way it would be transformed would be up to each derived class. Does that help?

Comment: Why do you need that string at all? `transform` is pure virtual anyway, and some data types might implment a separate parser instead of a regex. `transform` is protected - if you don't use it in base class functions, better drop it entirely. If you intend to pass raw and formatted to transform (in base class), you might prefer making them private.

Answer (score 0):

In general in C++ static data members must be defined outside the class (usually in .cpp file) like this:

```
string IPv4Address::definition = "[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
```

In your case however, there is no particular need for this data member at all, especially in your base class `DataType`. Data members cannot be overridden in derived class, so when you declare `definition` member in `DataType` class and "redefine" it in `IPv4Address` class, you actually define two separate unrelated variables which will not help you in any way to use different patterns based on class type. For example:

```
void foo(DataType &data)
{
    cout << data.definition; // assuming "definition" is public for the sake of example
}

void bar()
{
    IPv4Address addr;
    foo(addr); // will output the DataType::definition and not IPv4Address::definition because the "definition" data member is not "virtual" and there is really no such thing
}
```

Given that your `Transform` method will be the one using this `definition` and is going to be different in every class, you can get rid of this data member altogether and just make it a part of `Transforms`'s definition.